# Number of ways in which some alphabets can be arranged .

Tags: permutations, combinations

The five vowels $A$, $E$, $I$, $O$ and $U$ along with$15$ $X$'s are to be arranged in a row such that no $X$ is at an extreme position. Also, between any two vowels there must be at least $3$ $X$'s. Find the number of ways in which this can be done.
I have tried but failed to get the correct answer. Please help me to give any reference to solve it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: By extreme position, do you mean no X's can be on the outside of the list?

Answer (score 4):

Here's my method. There are $5!$ ways to order the $A,E,I,O,U$. Next we need to decide in how many ways can we put the $X$'s in between those vowels. We need at least three in between any of them, so that's already $4\cdot3=12$ $X$'s, and hence we've got 3 $X$'s left to distribute. We now have three options: (1) put all three $X$'s between the same two vowels. This gives 4 possibilities. (2) Put two $X$'s between the same pair of vowels and the other one between a different pair. This gives $4\cdot 3=12$ possibilities. And finally (3) we could put all three $X$'s between three different pairs of vowels. That gives 
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
4 \\
3
\end{pmatrix} = \frac{4!}{3!1!} = 4
\end{align}
possibilities as this is the number of ways we can choose $3$ out of the $4$ pairs. In total then, we get
\begin{align}
5!\cdot \left(4 + 12 + 4 \right) = 120\cdot 20 = 2400
\end{align}
possibilities, which agrees with CY Aries's answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are $5$ choices of the last letter, which is a vowel. Each of the remaining $4$ vowels must be followed by at least $3$ X's. We can take a vowel followed by $3$ X's as a group. There are $3$ free X's left. Besides the last letter, we have now $7$ objects ($4$ groups and $3$ free X's). One of the $4$ groups must appear first. We have to arrange the $3$ remaining groups among the $6$ positions. The number of ways is $\displaystyle P_3^6$. The total number of ways to arrange the letters is

$$5\times4 \times P_3^6=2400$$

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: Typographical error:  You meant we have to arrange the $\color{red}{3}$ remaining groups among the six positions.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yes. Forgot to correct when editing the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

AEIOU can be arranged in 5!. As X's can't be at extreme ends and there are minimum of 3 X's in between two vowels. Hence there remains 3 X which can be arranged in 4 place in such a way. 
let x1, x2,x3 &  x4 are the place among the vowels (A (x1) E (x2) I (x3)  O (x4) U).
$x1+x2+x3+x4=3$ (the no of solution to this polynomials are)
$4+3-1C4-1= 20$ way.
Hence total no of solution is $5!*20=2400$

Answer (score 0):

I'm no genius, but i think this is how it's done.

Since 3 X's must be placed between each vowel, that's means 12 X's are already assigned positions, leaving three to be arranged in other ways. There are 3! = 6 ways of doing this.

On top of that, there are 5 vowels and therefore 5! = 120 ways of arranging these.

Then 5! • 3! = 120 • 6 = 720 possible ways

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Your claim that there are $3!$ ways of arranging the remaining three X's is false.  Let $x_k$ be the number of free $X$'s between the $k$th and $(k + 1)$st vowel.  Then $$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 3$$  This is an equation in the nonnegative integers.  This is a [combination with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition) problem. The number of solutions is the number of ways we can insert three addition signs in a row of three ones, which is $\binom{6}{3}$ since we must choose which three of the six positions will be filled with addition signs.

Comment: Cheers, thought I'd have a go anyway :)